# How do i assign each files in an index from the List to another pictureBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

In Form1 im creating 8 pictureBoxes in the constructor:

```
pbs = new PictureBox[8];
            progressbars = new ProgressBar[8];
            for (int i = 0; i < pbs.Length; i++)
            {
                progressbars[i] = new ProgressBar();
                progressbars[i].Size = new Size(100, 10);
                progressbars[i].Margin = new Padding(0, 0, 0, 70);
                progressbars[i].Dock = DockStyle.Top;
                pbs[i] = new PictureBox();
                pbs[i].MouseEnter += globalPbsMouseEnterEvent;
                pbs[i].MouseLeave += globalPbsMouseLeaveEvent;
                pbs[i].Tag = "PB" + i.ToString();
                pbs[i].Size = new Size(100, 100);
                pbs[i].Margin = new Padding(0, 0, 0, 60);
                pbs[i].Dock = DockStyle.Top;
                pbs[i].SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                Panel p = i < 4 ? panel1 : panel2;
                p.Controls.Add(pbs[i]);
                p.Controls.Add(progressbars[i]);
                pbs[i].BringToFront();
                progressbars[i].BringToFront();
            }
```

In timer1 tick event i assign the images to a pictureBox in a loop so it will look like animation.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < file_array.Length; i++)
                {

                }
                if (leave == true)
                {
                    pb.Load(file_array[file_indxs]);
                }
                else
                {
                    pbs[0].Load(file_array[file_indxs]);
                }
                file_indxs = file_indxs + 1;
                if (file_indxs >= file_array.Length)
                {
                    file_indxs = 0;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                timer1.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
```

And file_array is string[] im creating it by getting the files from the directories:

```
private void getfiles()
        {
            List<FileInfo> fileList = new List<FileInfo>();
            for (int i = 0; i < BackgroundWorkerConfiguration.urlsDirectories.Count; i++)
            {
                System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(BackgroundWorkerConfiguration.urlsDirectories[i]);
                fileList.AddRange(di.GetFiles("*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                                    .Where(x => x.Length > 0).Select(y => y));
            }
            var file_array = fileList.OrderBy(x => x.CreationTime)
                                .GroupBy(x => x.DirectoryName)
                                .Select(g => g.Select(x => x.FullName).ToList())
                                .ToArray();
            timer1.Enabled = true;
        }
```

Now in the timer tick event i loop over the file_array and assign all the images to the first pictureBox: pbs[0]

But now the variable file_array is not the same. Before it was just string[] with many files inside of images.

Now file_array is like this:

in index 0 i have 48 files.
in index 1 index 2 index and index 4 there are 61 files in each index.

I want in the timer tick event to assign each index of file to another pictureBox.
So index 0 in the file_array all the 48 files should be assign to pbs[0]
Index 1 the files should be assign to pbs[1]...
And so on untill index 4 to assign to pbs[4]

But i dont want to write as i did before pbs[0].Load...
I want that it will automatic load the images from file_array indexs to the pictureBoxes.
The first files in index 0 to the first pictureBox and so on...

EDIT**

```
public void globalPbsMouseEnterEvent(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            PictureBox p = sender as PictureBox;
            if (p.Tag.ToString() == "PB0")
            {
                pb.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                pb.Visible = true;
                pb.BringToFront();
                leave = true;
            }
            else
            {
            }
        }

        public void globalPbsMouseLeaveEvent(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            PictureBox p = sender as PictureBox;
            if (p.Tag.ToString() == "PB0")
            {
                if (leave == true)
                {
                    pb.Visible = false;
                    leave = false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
            }
        }


private void pb_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pb.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            pb.Visible = true;
            pb.BringToFront();
            leave = true;
        }

        private void pb_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (leave == true)
            {
                pb.Visible = false;
                leave = false;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace this `pbs[0].Load(file_array[file_indxs]);` with `pbs[file_indxs].Load(file_array[file_indxs]);`. Note that the `file_indxs` should be initialized to `0`.

### UPDATE

Try this to animate the PictureBox with the files list input:

```
//Use this custom PictureBox for convenience
public class AnimatedPictureBox : PictureBox {
  List<string> imageFilenames;
  Timer t = new Timer();
  public AnimatedPictureBox(){
    AnimateRate = 100; //It's up to you, the smaller, the faster.
    t.Tick += Tick_Animate;      
  }
  public int AnimateRate {
    get { return t.Interval; } 
    set { t.Interval = value;}
  }
  public void Animate(List<string> imageFilenames){
    this.imageFilenames = imageFilenames;
    t.Start();
  }
  public void StopAnimate(){
    t.Stop();
    i = 0;
  }
  int i;
  private void Tick_Animate(object sender, EventArgs e){
    if(imageFilenames == null) return;
    Load(imageFilenames[i]);
    i = (i+1)%imageFilenames.Count;
  }
}

//Now use the AnimatedPictureBox instead of the PictureBox
AnimatedPictureBox[] pbs = new AnimatedPictureBox[8];
//Animate all the PictureBoxes
for(int i = 0; i < file_array.Length; i++){
  pbs[i].Animate(file_array[i]);
}
```

The `getfiles` should return the array of `List<string>`, assign the return value to the `file_array` you define in the outside scope:

```
//Note that you now don't need your timer1, just remove it.
private List<string>[] getfiles() {
   //....
   return file_array;
}
//When calling getfiles, 
//you have to assign the file_array variable to the return value
List<string>[] file_array; //your variable, you defined it as string[], 
                           //but it won't work, we have to use List<string>[]
file_array = getfiles();
```

**NOTE**: If you want to stop animation on a Picturebox, just call the method `StopAnimate`. That's all.

Comment: @DoronMuzar you should declare a **global** variable `file_array`. The `file_array` in `getfiles` has type `List<string>[]` (an array of `List<string>`). It's different from the `file_array` you defined in the outside scope. It's not clear what you want to do with the `timer1`. You should make it clear, the code is not enough because the code itself has something wrong.

Comment: King in the timer i want to animate the images from the file_array. I want to assign each index files from the file_array into a pictureBox and using the timer to display the images like animation. Like animated gif.

Comment: @DoronMuzar that means you have 8 pictureBoxs to **animate**. So the question is **When do you animate them?** Animate them altogether or each by each? Each animation requires a loop via all the frame images.

Comment: Knig animate them all togeather. In this case file_array contain 5 indexs so only the first 5 picutreBoxes should banimated. If there are 8 indexs then 8 pictureBoxes. And yes all togeather should be animated at once. The pictureBoxes are small and i did that when i move the mouse over one of the pictureBoxes it will show the animation on big one pictureBox in the middle. When i move the mouse out of the big pictureBox it will keep animate it in the small ones. The small ones should be animated all the time none stop only when moving the mouse in/out should animate the pictureBox the mouse is

Comment: In and out. Thats why i used a timer. I want the pictureBoxes to animate togeather all the time.

Comment: King in general the answer is yes animate them all togeather.

Comment: @DoronMuzar if so using a Timer is too intensive, you should use 1 Timer for each PictureBox (so we need 8 timers). Even doing like that may make your UI a little irresponsive.

Comment: I added the code to my question of the mouse enter mouse leave for the pictureBoxes and for the pb(the big pictureBox in the middle).

Comment: King then i have to add somehow 8 timers and activate them according to the file_array indexs. if its 5 then 5 timers to run . Maybe using a background worker with the timers will make it better for the UI irresponsive ? But if its not that matter then first to try it regular with 8 timers.

Comment: Then how do you make array of timers ?

Comment: Ok creating array of timers is easy. So i need to create array of timers then loop in each timer for the array list and add an index files for a different pictureBox ?

Comment: @DoronMuzar you don't need to create array of timers yourself, doing that may be error-prone, you just need to define some custom PictureBox, see the updated code.

Comment: King a question: In the constructor i did pbs = new pictureBox[8]; then in the button click event i did your code pbs = new AnimatedPictureBox[8]; is that ok that pbs have two instances in the constructor to create the pictureBoxes and then the instance for your code ?

Comment: Second problem on this line: pbs[i].Animate(file_array[i]); im getting an error that Animate is not exist on pbs. I added the AnimatedPictureBox class to the bottom of my code but animate is not exist.

Comment: @DoronMuzar please post your code you tried. It's too strange. The `Animate` is **obviously** defined in the classs `AnimatedPictureBox`. Your `pbs` **should be declared as `AnimatedPictureBox`** NOT `PictureBox`.

Comment: @DoronMuzar your old code uses this `PictureBox[] pbs = new AnimatedPictureBox[8];` but it should be `AnimatedPictureBox[] pbs = new AnimatedPictureBox[8];` Otherwise you have to cast the element to `AnimatedPictureBox` before using `Animate` method.